# Container LAMP com Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, docker, lamp

Realizei algumas buscas na internet e não encontrei instruções para montar um container LAMP utilizando a imagem oficial Debian Stretch (https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/). A ideia seria subir um container Docker com Apache2.4, PHP7.0 e MariaDB 10.3 (para isso seria utilizado Docker-compose 3.3 e Dockerfile).

Obs: Compreendo que o ideal seria não subir tudo em um único container, entretanto, se possível, neste cenário especifico, gostaria de integrar em um único container a estrutura LAMP, no pior cenário o banco poderia ficar em um container a parte.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Minha primeira reação teria sido criar uma imagem customizada com a stack. Como nunca usei `Docker`, não posso falar o como fazer isso, da dificuldade envolvida, confiabilidade dessa solução "caseira" nem o como de fato fazer isso

Comment: a sua ideia seria criar 3 containers, cada um com um servico ou manter os 3 servicos em um so container?

Comment: Juntos. Sei que em 99% dos cenários não seja o correto, porém, essa é uma necessidade pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De "diferente" de um setup standalone é que você terá rodando mais de um processo no teu *container*. Não que *containers* tenham sido feitos para rodar um único processo/serviço, mas fazer tudo em um, além de "engessar" a estrutura do *container* e fazer com que ele tenha diversas responsabilidades acaba tirando algumas vantagens que eles trazem, como facilidade de monitoramento do serviço/*container*, complexidade de gestão dos processos, manutenibilidade da imagem - mesmo usando um provisionador como puppet ou chef -, etc.

De toda forma um exemplo de como disponibilizar isto seria usando algo que permita rodar, com confiabilidade, mais de um processo no *container*. Para isto irei usar o [Honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho), mas tem outras formas como o próprio [*supervisord*](http://supervisord.org/) ou até mesmo um script que inicia todos os serviço, comumente visto.

A opção por *Honcho* é a simplicidada no uso e gestão dos serviços, com *supervisord* a configuração é mais extensa e a padrão gera constantemente erro nos *containers*. Aqui tem um exemplo usando *supervisord* que até fala em não usar muitos processos num mesmo *container*: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/

---

Estes seriam todos os passos necessários para o que você precisa:

- instalação e configuração do Honcho
- instalação e configuração do Apache2.4
- instalação e configuração do Maria DB 10.3
- instalação e configuração do PHP 7.0

Não vou instalar e nem configurar tudo, apenas parte com o *Honcho* configurado e rodando os serviços do Apache e Maria DB. O restante, com instalação e configuração do PHP, configurações dinâmicas, e outros pormenores que precise basta fazer conforme sua necessidade.

---

Vamos começar adiciona o repositório do Maria DB, além de alguns utilitários para o *apt*. Esta parte ficará assim e é auto-explicativa:

```
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common gnupg; \
    apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8; \
    add-apt-repository 'deb http://mariadb.biz.net.id/repo/10.3/debian stretch main'
```

Feito isso iremos instalar o Apache, Maria DB e `pip`, gerenciador de pacote Python, que utilizaremos para instalar o *Honcho*, no `Dockerfile` teríamos algo como isto:

```
RUN { \
        echo "mariadb-server-10.3" mysql-server/root_password password 'unused'; \
        echo "mariadb-server-10.3" mysql-server/root_password_again password 'unused'; \
    } | debconf-set-selections; \
    apt-get install -y apache2 mariadb-common mariadb-server python-pip; \
    sed -Ei 's/^(bind-address|log)/#&/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

De diferente aí apenas setamos os valores padrão da configuração de senha do Maria DB, para não ser preciso interagir com a console ao construir a imagem do *docker*, comentamos algumas configurações do Maria DB que costumam gerar erros e por fim apagamos o cache do *apt*, para a imagem ficar menor.

Por último o *Honcho*, para ele iremos precisar de um [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile), arquivo onde especificamos quais comandos devem ser executados para iniciar os serviços. O conteúdo dele será isto:

```
apache: /usr/sbin/apachectl -DFOREGROUND
mariadb: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --timezone=UTC
```

O formato dele é bem simples, o primeiro elemento é o nome do processo e o segundo é o comando para rodar o processo.

No  `Dockerfile` pra instalar teremos isto:

```
RUN pip install honcho
```

E isto para compiar o nosso `Procfile` para a imagem e definir o diretório de trabalho em `/`, que é onde por padrão o *Honcho* busca pelo `Procfile`:

```
ADD Procfile /Procfile

WORKDIR /
```

Para iniciar o *Honcho* e ele levantar os serviços do Apache e Maria DB, usaremos o `CMD` mesmo, assim:

```
CMD honcho start
```

Esta seria a versão completa do nosso `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:stretch

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# adiciona repositório do mariadb
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common gnupg; \
    apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8; \
    add-apt-repository 'deb http://mariadb.biz.net.id/repo/10.3/debian stretch main'

# instalando apache2, mariadb e python-pip
RUN { \
        echo "mariadb-server-10.3" mysql-server/root_password password 'unused'; \
        echo "mariadb-server-10.3" mysql-server/root_password_again password 'unused'; \
    } | debconf-set-selections; \
    apt-get install -y apache2 mariadb-common mariadb-server python-pip; \
    sed -Ei 's/^(bind-address|log)/#&/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# instalando o honcho
RUN pip install honcho

ADD Procfile /Procfile

EXPOSE 80 443 3306

WORKDIR /

CMD honcho start
```

Você pode organizar os comando conforme achar melhor para gerar menos *layers* e ter uma imagem menor.

A nossa *docker-compose* de exemplo ficaria assim:

```
version: '3'
services:
  lamp:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: sample_multi_process
    image: brunocesar/sample-multi-process:0.0.1-snapshot
    ports:
      - 90:80
```

Na *docker-compose* você poderá usar o que precisar, como mapear os [*volumes*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes), ter uma [*network*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks) específica, [*deploy*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy), [etc.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Verificando que tudo está ok com `docker-compose ps`:

```
[bruno@bruno docker-multi-process]$ docker-compose ps
        Name                   Command           State                   Ports                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sample_multi_process   /bin/sh -c honcho start   Up      3306/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:90->80/tcp
```

Você poderá ver os detalhes com `docker-compose logs -f --tail 20`, por exemplo, ou acessar a página padrão do Apache em http://localhost:90 - pode ser que o seu não esteja roteando corretamente, então vai pelo IP da *docker machine*.

Finalizando, existem diversos exemplos de LAMP num único container, como a a [linode/lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/linode/lamp/) e a [dell/lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/dell/lamp/), então você poderá montar a sua conforme achar mais interessante. Além disso, uma [busca por LAMP](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=lamp) no Docker Hub/Store irá retornar bastante coisa,

Comment: O que seria essa linha: image: brunocesar/sample-multi-process:0.0.1-snapshot? Já que no Dockerfile tem a referencia para imagem: FROM debian:stretch

Comment: @Fábio é o nome da imagem que será criada. O `FROM debian:stretch` é a imagem base, o `brunocesar/sample-multi-process` a imagem customizada e o `0.0.1-snapshot` a tag/versão dela.

Comment: Ótimo, já testei aqui. Essa imagem personalizada é a imagem que será criada a partir do build, certo?

Comment: Exatamente @Fábio, é o equivalente a `docker build -t brunocesar/sample-multi-process:0.0.1-snapshot ...`, só que tudo junto aqui na compose.

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo nada de errado em ter uma imagem com todo o software necessário para rodar o sistema. Isso é normal para quem usa Docker para testes de integração.

Eu não tenho muita experiência com Docker, considere o que vou dizer como uma sugestão:

Ache um Dockerfile que faça o que você quer.
No momento, https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/lamp/~/dockerfile/ parece um bom candidato.
Como ele é baseado em Ubuntu, eu só mudaria:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

para

```
FROM debian:stretch
```

Você pode fazer o fork do repositório: https://github.com/fauria/docker-lamp