# Status Exited (0) após um comando docker-compose up

Tags: docker

Estou começando a trabalhar com o Docker agora, entendo bem os conceitos de imagens e containers mas estou com um problema para rodar o comando:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Eu criei um `Dockerfile` na raiz do meu projeto para criar um container com os principais componentes que preciso para minha aplicação rodar:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial-20180525
MAINTAINER Matheus Freitas <matheus.freitas@ibti.net.br>
RUN mkdir /home/sog-imn/
ADD . /home/sog-imn
WORKDIR /home/sog-imn
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y erlang
RUN apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server
RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y maven
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN npm install bower -g
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
RUN npm install gulp -D
RUN npm install less -g
RUN npm install browser-sync -g
EXPOSE 8081
```

Fiz a composição do Dockerfile com o `docker-compose.yml`, criando as networks:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - backend
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - postegres
networks:
  backend:
  postegres:
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Quando eu rodo o comando:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Aparentemente está tudo certo no log do console...

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Matheus:sog-imn matheusfreitas$ docker-compose up
Creating sog-imn_app_1 ... done
Creating sog-imn_db_1  ... done
Attaching to sog-imn_app_1, sog-imn_db_1
sog-imn_app_1 exited with code 0
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-06-18 13:38:31 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Quando rodo o comando:

```
$ docker ps -a
```

O Conatiner App esta com o e status

```
Exited (0) 6 seconds ago
```

Não entendo o porque disso, gostaria de mais algumas informações sobre os possíveis problemas que eu posso estar ocasionando e se possível dicas de como resolver esses problemas.

Comment: O seu container não está rodando nada, então assim que criado será parado mesmo, um container docker termina a execução assim que seu processo principal termina. Qual seria o `ENTRYPOINT\CMD` para executar tua aplicação?

Comment: Olá Bruno, a minha aplicação roda o comando mvn spring-boot:run <- acho que esse seria o meu CMD agora o ENTRYPOINT não tenho certeza mas acho que seria o diretório no qual executo o comando mvn spring-boot:run, me corrija se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Certo. Inclua no final do `Dockerfile` isto: `ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]`. Neste caso não precisa de um `CMD`, só que quiser passar algum parâmetro e tal. Outros pontos: você pode usar a imagem do [maven](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/), além de usar o rabbitmq em um outro container. Não sei o que tem nesse shell script seu, nem como está sua aplicação, mas você precisará mexer na sua imagem para rodar dois serviços no container. Veja nesta resposta como rodar mais de um serviço:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240037/241084#241084

Comment: Bruno consegui fazer o banco rodar, muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Show, depois posta tua solução como resposta, pode ser útil para outras pessoas.

Comment: O que aprece no console quando vc executa?  docker-compose up

Answer (score 2):

Os containers usam um conceito de que tem que executar o que for pedido e depois morrer, ou seja, contêiner é feito para morrer.

O que esta acontecendo é que o contêiner está executando todas as tarefas e depois morre, você precisa iniciar uma aplicação que vai deixar ele vivo (ou de pé),
quando você roda o `docker exec my_image /bin/bash` você está iniciando o processo do terminal que mantem ele vivo.

No seu caso tente passar na imagem ou no docker-compose o que deve ser executado.

Dockerfile

```
CMD [ "python3" , "app.py" ]
```

Equivale a no terminal que vai executar um script:
$ python3 app.py

Tente adaptar ao seu projeto.

> [Leia isso pode te ajudar](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-entrypoint-cmd-dockerfile-best-practices-abc591c30e21)

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo, legal não sabia disso :) Excelente explicação.

Answer (score -1):

Já tentou adicionar a tag tty? Segue exemplo:

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:

    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - backend
  tty: true
```

Funcionou para mim quando estava utilizando um servidor nginx e mysql db